# how to hide source code like on lionsgate's website?

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption

I wanted to ask you how it is possible to hide the source code like on Lionsgate's website: https://www.lionsgate.com/

If you head over to: view-source:https://www.lionsgate.com/
Here is the code from view-source:

```
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="_EvDO8qIZmbl1NWIapBahEQsFlFGFPsfJQnLfFXU1To" />

    <!-- <meta property="og:title" content="LIONSGATE" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Lionsgate is a global content platform whose films, television series, digital products and linear and over-the-top platforms reach next generation audiences around the world." />
    <meta property="og:image" name="Lionsgate" content="/media/images/logo-ogimage.jpg" />

    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.Lionsgate.com" />    
    <meta property="og:type" content="Entertainment" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Lionsgate.com - Official Company Website" /> -->

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/media/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/media/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/media/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/media/favicon/site.webmanifest">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


    <!-- experimental GTM  -->
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T9Q8QNQ');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <!-- //experimental GTM  -->




    <!-- BEGIN Salesforce DMP ControlTag for "http://lionsgate.com" -->
    <script class="kxct" data-id="Kwl-bwdx" data-timing="async" data-version="3.0" type="text/javascript">
        window.Krux||((Krux=function(){Krux.q.push(arguments)}).q=[]);
        (function(){
        var k=document.createElement('script');k.type='text/javascript';k.async=true;
        k.src=(location.protocol==='https:'?'https:':'http:')+'//cdn.krxd.net/controltag/Kwl-bwdx.js';
        var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(k,s);
        }());
    </script>
    <!-- END Salesforce DMP ControlTag -->
<link href="/css/style.0a622347abc8901f65ef.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.0a622347abc8901f65ef.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

As you can see there is almost no html code just the

Does any of you know how can I encrypt/ hide the code in that way?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: The code is not encrypted

Comment: You use a single-page application; all of the work's being done by JavaScript.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you can't hide anything from a user on their own computer.  If you've got information you **do** want to hide from the user, just don't send it to them!

Answer (score 1):

The source code is not hidden. Here it is: https://www.lionsgate.com/js/main.0a622347abc8901f65ef.js

I recommend you read more about [single-page react application](https://www.google.ca/search?q=single-page%20react%20application).

In short, they load a [javascript bundle](https://www.lionsgate.com/js/main.0a622347abc8901f65ef.js) which renders their HTML into the page instead of rendering the HTML on the server-side. This is a pretty common approach with client-side frameworks like react.

They are not obfuscating or hiding anything.